# When i try to creat google map the exception error occur

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

If i Try to create a Google Map in My device,I have Imported my Google play Services lib file in My SDK and then i tried to run my app but it will showing me the error of unfortunately Stopped your Apps, and in Log chat i will get the following error help me to fix this error

```
03-06 11:13:48.112: W/dalvikvm(1108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a7bb90)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Process: com.example.finalmap, PID: 1108
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.finalmap/com.example.finalmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.example.finalmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 11 more
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.D(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.T(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.S(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.nO(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4784)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-06 11:13:48.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 21 more
03-06 11:14:10.782: I/Process(1108): Sending signal. PID: 1108 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post your layout xml file

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" /> </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong in your `XML layout` as well as `Setting up the google play service` , which official doc [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Please try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will finally get a map on your phone.

`MainAcitivity`, sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private EditText et_address, et_finalAddress;
    LatLng addressPos, finalAddressPos;
    Marker addressMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        et_finalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalAddressEditText);


        // Initial Map
        try {

            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // Put a dot on my current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        // 3D building
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        // Get zoom button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(goodLatLng)
                .title("Hello"));
    }
```

For more details, please refer to my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did u register ur app in google?

I think u didn't put the right Api key,

If not, u have to register ur app and put ur app's API key in AndroidManifest.xml.

[Register Here](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Please read the Google Map API Documentation.

Comment: No sir i Actually Register mine in Google Apis console  and i have pasted that key in my androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: but in your error, it showing "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />"

Comment: <uses-feature
 android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
 android:required="true" /><meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyD_n3ze65BaKBmt_DC33HYge89wVYoFPrY" /><application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ><activity
android:name="com.example.finalmap.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" > <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity></application>